# Is it possible to edit files in one project while running another project in the same solution in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, editing

Almost all of our Windows projects consist of a WCF windows hosted service and then a WPF client application. All of these have usually been split into two different solutions, one for the service, one for the client. This was done for various reasons, but we recently were looking at possibly putting them all together on a new project, which we did. This would mean not having to run two copies of Visual Studio and make it easier for various other things.

Our concern now is being able to edit the WPF client while debuging the service. Many of the developers will keep the service running a large part of the day when making changes in the client. But it looks like with this setup, when you start debuging the service, Visual Studio will not let you edit any of the other code in the solution.

Is there a way around this, so that you could have the service running whenever you want, and still be able to edit the WPF and CS files in the other project? Or should these two parts stay in two separate solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want two instances of Visual Studio: one doing the debugging of the service and the other one for coding.

You could also imagine having the service running without the debugger attached, and only attach it manually when you're ready to launch/debug the client you were working on.